# Some doubts about proof of Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers, strong-convergence

I quote *Jacod-Protter*.

> **Theorem:**
>  Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ be independent and identically distributed and defined on the same space. Let$$\mu=\mathbb{E}\{X_j\}$$ $$\sigma^2=\sigma_{X_j}^2<\infty$$ Let $S_n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_j$. Then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_j=\mu\hspace{0.3cm}\text{ a.s. and in }L^2$$
>
> > **Part of the proof:**
> >  (Assume $S_n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_j$ and $Y_n=\frac{S_n}{n}$. After some passages, assuming, without loss of generality, that $\mu=0$, one gets to $\lim\mathbb{E}\{Y_n^2\}=0$, that is $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$)
> >     Since $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$, there is a subsequence converging to $0$ a.s. 
> > However we want the original sequence to converge a.s. To do this, we find a subsequence converging a.s. and then treat the terms in between successive terms of the subsequence.
> >     Since $\mathbb{E}\{Y_n^2\}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, let's choose the subsequence $n^2$; then $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\{Y_{n^2}^2 \}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}<\infty$$
> >     therefore we also know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n^2}^{2}<\infty$ a.s., hence the tail of this convergent series converges to $0$; we conclude 
> >     \begin{equation}
> > \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Y_{n^2}=0 \hspace{0.5cm}\text{a.s.}\tag{1}
> > \end{equation}
> >     
> >  Next let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $p(n)$ be the integer such that $p(n)^2\le n<\left(p\left(n\right)+1\right)^2$. Then $$Y_n-\frac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}=\frac{1}{n}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=p(n)^2+1}^{n}X_j}$$ and $$\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(Y_n-\frac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right)^2\right\}=\frac{n-p(n)^2}{n^2}\sigma^2$$
> >     $(...)$
> >     
> >     Since, by $(1)$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Y_{p(n)^2}=0 \text{ a.s.}$ and since $\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}\rightarrow 1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Y_n=0\text{ a.s.}$ as well.

I have some doubts about the above-quoted proof *(Herebelow I quote parts arising doubts, then I describe my doubts in detail, finally I summarize the doubts in **bold**)*:
1. $\text{"}$ therefore we also know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n^2}^{2}<\infty$ a.s., hence the tail of this convergent series converges to $0$; we conclude 
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Y_{n^2}=0 \hspace{0.5cm}\text{a.s. "}
\end{equation}

As far as I know, if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n^2}^{2}<\infty$ a.s., then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Y_{n^2}^2=0 \hspace{0.2cm}\text{a.s.}$. Hence, **why is the above conclusion on $Y_{n^2}$ (that is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Y_{n^2}=0 \hspace{0.2cm}\text{a.s.}$) and NOT on $Y_{n^2}^2$ as I would expect (that is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Y_{n^2}^2=0 \hspace{0.2cm}\text{a.s.}$)**?
2.$\text{"}$ $\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(Y_n-\frac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right)^2\right\}=\dfrac{n-p(n)^2}{n^2}\sigma^2$ $\text{"}$
 Why does it hold true? I know that, by linearity of expectation, $\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(Y_n-\frac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right)^2\right\}=\mathbb{E}\{Y_n^2\}+\mathbb{E}\left\{\dfrac{p(n)^4}{n^2}Y_{p(n)^2}^2\right\}-2\mathbb{E}\left\{Y_n\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right\}$
 I know how to show that $\mathbb{E}\{Y_n^2\}=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and $\mathbb{E}\left\{\dfrac{p(n)^4}{n^2}Y_{p(n)^2}^2\right\}=\dfrac{p(n)^2\sigma^2}{n^2}$.
 However, I cannot show that $\mathbb{E}\left\{Y_n\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right\}=\dfrac{p(n)^2\sigma^2}{n^2}$ so as to get to the above conclusion $$\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(Y_n-\frac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right)^2\right\}=\dfrac{n-p(n)^2}{n^2}\sigma^2$$
 **Could you please show me why it does hold that $\mathbb{E}\left\{Y_n\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right\}=\dfrac{p(n)^2\sigma^2}{n^2}$?**
3. $\text{"}$ $\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}\rightarrow 1$ $\text{"}$ 
 I understand the above-quoted result intuitively, but I cannot show it mathematically. 
**Could you please show me how to show that $\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}\rightarrow 1$ as $n\to\infty$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), we are using [the fact from real analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600067/215011):

> If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers with $\lim a_n^2=0$, then also $\lim a_n=0$.

For (2), the entity
$$
A_n:=Y_n-\frac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}=\frac{1}{n}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=p(n)^2+1}^{n}X_j}\tag1
$$
is a constant ($\frac1n$) times the sum of IID random variables (the $X_j$) each with zero mean; so $A_n$ has zero mean. Conclude$$E(A_n^2)\stackrel{(a)}=\operatorname{Var}(A_n)\stackrel{(b)}=\frac1{n^2}\sum \operatorname{Var}(X_j)\stackrel{(c)}=\frac1{n^2}\sum\sigma^2,\tag2$$
where $(a)$ is the fact $E(A_n)=0$, $(b)$ is independence, and $(c)$ is the fact that each $X_j$ has the same variance $\sigma^2$. It remains to count the number of terms in the sum, which is $n-\rho(n)^2$.

---

EDIT: If you wish to show $\mathbb{E}\left\{Y_n\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right\}=\dfrac{p(n)^2\sigma^2}{n^2}$, write
$V_n:=\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}$ so that $$Y_n\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}=Y_nV_n=(Y_n-V_n)V_n + V_n^2.\tag3$$ Note that $Y_n-V_n$ involves only $X_j$ for $j>\rho(n)^2$ while $V_n$ involves $X_j$ with $j\le\rho(n)^2$, hence $Y_n-V_n$ is independent of $V_n$. Since $V_n$ has mean zero, the expectation of (3) is $0+{\mathbb E}(V_n^2)$ which you've shown to equal $\dfrac{p(n)^2\sigma^2}{n^2}$.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference for the answer to the first question? I cannot find it :( As to the answer to the second question, it is perfect! Just one thing: if instead I wanted to maintain my approach, do you think would there be a simple way to compute $\mathbb{E}\left\{Y_n\dfrac{p(n)^2}{n}Y_{p(n)^2}\right\}$ and so to show it is equal to $\dfrac{p(n)^2\sigma^2}{n^2}$? Thank you a lot for all your help @grand_chat

Comment: Please see my edits above.

Comment: Thank you a lot, got it :)

Answer (score 1):

The last question is easy.

$\sqrt{n}-1 < p(n) \le \sqrt{n}$.

Squaring,
$n-2\sqrt{n}+1 < p^2(n)\le n$
so that
$1-\frac{2\sqrt{n}-1}{n}
\lt \frac{p^2(n)}{n}
\le 1
$
which shows that
$\frac{p^2(n)}{n}
\to 1$
since
$\frac{2\sqrt{n}-1}{n} \to 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I already knew that $\dfrac{p^2(n)}{n}\le 1$ by your same argument, but I was not sure that this was enough to state that $\dfrac{p^2(n)}{n}\rightarrow1$. So, why is this enough? For example, $\dfrac{n}{n^2}\le1$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, so it follows that $\dfrac{n}{n^2}\rightarrow1$ as $n\to\infty$? Why? @martycohen

Comment: I added a additional explanation.

Comment: Oooh, I should have understood that on my own! Sorry and thank you a lot for your kindness @martycohen

Comment: Pardon, could you someway please help me with the first two questions as well? @martycohen